# Prove Bezout Equation Problem

Tags: proof-writing, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I have this math problem, that I'm kind of confused on.

> Consider the equation $a x + b y = c$, for some non-zero integers $a,
>  b$ and $c$.  Suppose that $x = x_1, y = y_1$ is an integer solution to
>    the equation $ax + by = c$.
>
> i)  Show that for any $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $$ x = x_1+
>  \frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}m, y=y_1 -
>  \frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}m $$ will also satisfy the equation $ax + by = c$
>    and hence is also an integer solution.
>
> ii)  It is know that if $x, y$ is an integer solution to the
>    homogeneous equation $a x + by = 0$, then $$ x = \frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}
>  k,  y= - \frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)} k,  \text{ for some
>  integer } k. $$ Use this fact to show that if $x=x_2, y=y_2$ is
>    another solution to the equation  $a x + b y = c$, then $$ x_2 = x_1+
>  \frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}k,  y_2=y_1 -
>  \frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}k, \text{ for some integer } k. $$

I'm not 100% sure on how to start i). I know that $\gcd(a, b)$ can be represented as $ar+bs=\gcd(a,b)$. But I'm not sure how to go about answering this question. Thanks.

Comment: For 1), plug in the proposed values of $x$ and $y$ into the expression $ac+by$. After some simplification, you should get $c$. That will finish the proof of 1).

Comment: @AndréNicolas, why would I plug it into $ac+by$?

Comment: Sorry, typo, plug in into $ax+by$. After a short calculation you will get $c$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, so I do this: $a(x_1+\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}\cdot m)+b(y_1-\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}\cdot m)=c$?

Comment: Look at the left-hand side of your expression only. Multiply out. We get $ax_1+\frac{abm}{\gcd(a,b)}+by_1-\frac{abm}{\gcd(a,b)}$. There is cancellation, and we get $ax_1+by_1$. But we were told that $ax_1+by_1=c$. So $ax+by=c$ for the above choice of $x$ and $y$.